# TypeError: Cannot read property 'reloadTable' of undefined

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Soy nuevo con vuejs, pero se me está dando el caso de que necesito desde un componente llamar a una función de otro.

Tengo un componente llamado **allUser** este tiene un método `cargar()` y otro `reloadTable()`.

Por otro lado tengo otro componente que se llama **buttonView** que tiene una función `deleteUser(id)` al cual se le pasa el `id` del usuario a eliminar y dentro de esta función hay un `confirm` y un `axios.post(url, {_method: 'DELETE'} )` que lo que hace es eliminar mi usuario.

Bien, el usuario se elimina perfectamente cuando confirmo, pero necesito si todo ha ido bien, hacer una llamada a la función `reloadTable()` del componente **allUser**.

Estoy intentando con:

```
_this.$refs.reloadTable();
```

pero la consola me devuelve este error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'reloadTable' of undefined

o si le paso como parámetro el array con las propiedades de mi datatable:

> TypeError: _this.$refs.reloadTable is not a function

Las funciones de **allUser**, de `cargar()` y reloadTable() son así:

```
cargar(url = this.url, options = this.tableProps){
  axios.get(url, { params: options } )
    .then((response) => {
      this.data = response.data;
    })
    .catch((error) => console.error(error));
},
reloadTable(tableProps) {
  this.cargar(this.url, tableProps);
},
```

y `tableProps` es:

```
tableProps: {
  search: '',
  length: 10,
  column: 'id',
  dir: 'asc'
},
```

Espero me puedan ayudar, gracias de antemano. He visto que había bastantes preguntas sobre esto, pero no he encontrado sobre vue, todo era angular o react.

---

**Update**:

*instancia de vue en laravl-8 en app.js*

```
require('./bootstrap');
window.Vue = require('vue').default;

Vue.component('alluser', require('./components/allUser.vue').default);
Vue.component('createuser', require('./components/createUser.vue').default);




import DataTable from 'laravel-vue-datatable';
 
Vue.use(DataTable);

  
const app = new Vue({
    el: '#contenedorVue',
});
```

Mi componente **allUser**:

```
<template>

    <div>

        <div class="">
            <data-table :data="data" :columns="columns" @on-table-props-changed="reloadTable"></data-table>
        </div>

    </div>

</template>


<script>
    import buttonView from './buttonView.vue';

    export default {
            data() {
            return {
                url: "/admin/vue/getAllUsers",
                data: {},
                tableProps: {
                    search: '',
                    length: 10,
                    column: 'id',
                    dir: 'asc'
                },
                columns: [
                    {
                        label: 'ID',
                        name: 'id',
                        orderable: true,
                    },
                    {
                        label: 'Name',
                        name: 'name',
                        orderable: true,
                    },
                    {
                        label: 'Email',
                        name: 'email',
                        orderable: true,
                    },
                    {
                        label: 'Acciones',
                        name: '',
                        orderable: false,
                        classes: { 
                            'btn': true,
                            'btn-primary': true,
                            'btn-sm': true,
                        },
                        event: "click",
                        component: buttonView
                    },
                ],
            }
        },
        components: {
            buttonView,
        },
        created() {
            this.cargar(this.url);
        },
        methods:{
            cargar(url = this.url, options = this.tableProps){
                axios.get(url, { params: options } )
                .then((response) => {
                    this.data = response.data;
                })
                .catch((error) => console.error(error));
            },
            reloadTable(tableProps) {
                this.cargar(this.url, tableProps);
            },
        },
    }
</script>
```

Mi componente **buttonView**:

```
   <template>
    <div>
        <div class="row">
            <a v-bind:href="'/admin/users/'+data.id+'/edit'">
                <button :class="classes" title="Update">
                    <span>
                        <i class="fas fa-user-edit"></i>
                    </span>
                </button>
            </a>
            <a href="#" @click="deleteUser(data.id)">
                <button :class="classes" title="Update">
                    <span>
                        <i class="fa fa-trash red"></i>
                    </span>
                </button>
                
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>

    export default {
        props: {
            data: {},
            name: {},
            props: ["id"],
            emit: "delete",
            click: {
                type: Function,
                default: () => {}
            },
            classes: {
                type: Object,
                default: () => ({ 
                    'btn': true,
                    'btn-primary': true,
                    'btn-sm': true,
                }),
            },
        },

        methods: {
            deleteUser(id) {
                
                if(confirm("¿Está seguro de que quiere eliminar el usuario con id ? " + id)){
                    let url = '/admin/users/' + id;

                   axios.post(url, { _method: 'DELETE' })
                    .then(response => {
                        // Lanzamos el evento
                        this.$emit("delete", this.id);
                    }).catch(error => {
                        console.log(error);
                    })
                }
            },
            
        }
            
    }
    
</script>
```

Comment: ¿El componente `ButtonView` está dentro del componente `AllUser`?

Comment: @BrayanMartínezSantana lo primero gracias por tu respuesta. Está importado. Actualizo mi pregunta para que puedas verlo

Comment: Si `buttonView` es un componente hijo del `allUser`, puedes [Emitir un valor con un Evento](https://es.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Emitiendo-un-valor-con-un-Evento) desde `buttonView` y escucharlo desde `allUser`.

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ Gracias por tu respuesta, pero no entiendo muy bien como aplicar la documentación... en decir en mi "click" ya estoy llamando a mi función. según la documentación, debería de usar "emit" para pasar un evento... pero no entiendo que debo enviarle ni como. También estoy confuso si es un hijo de allUser, ya que solo estoy importandolo

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ ahí he añadido todo mi código de mis dos componentes

Comment: ¿De dónde sale esa etiqueta `<data-table>`? no veo que estés importando un componente DataTable o algo así...

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ gracias por tu respuesta. Como dije en mi pregunta estoy usando laravel-8 para el back, entonces las llamas de vue se hacen desde el archivo. app.js. Lo añado a mi pregunta

Comment: Ahh... ok. Viendo la documentación de Laravel Vue Datatable, [este](https://jamesdordoy.github.io/laravel-vue-datatable/examples/injecting-dynamic-components) es el ejemplo de tu caso.

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ justamente esa es la librería que estoy usando y los ejemplos que intento usar.... pero ahora una vez eliminado el registro de la tabla, necesito actualizar esta

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ como se ve en mi componente allUser tengo dos botones uno para eliminar y otro para editar... en ese ejemplo se ve como añade un componente con un solo boton, yo añado un componente con dos botones, que no son botones realmente son enlaces ahref hacia rutas de laravel

Comment: No conozco esa librería, pero al parecer tendrías que poner cada botón en un componente distinto, y cada componente en una columna distinta con su propio evento y handler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Caso general (sin paquetes extras ni bibliotecas)

Puedes usar emitir un evento desde el componente hijo:

```
<template>
  <button @click="borra">Borrar {{ index }}</button>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: ["index"],
  emit: "delete",
  methods: {
    borra() {
      // Lanzamos el evento
      this.$emit("delete", this.index);
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Y en el componente padre puedes responder al evento con: `@[nombre del evento]`:

```
<template>
  <div>
    List/Tabla
    <div v-for="(elem,index) in arr" :key="index">
      {{ elem }}
      <ButtonView :index="index" @delete="updateTable"/>
    </div>

  </div>
</template>

<script>

import ButtonView from "./ButtonView";

export default {
  components: {ButtonView},
  data() {
    return {
      // esta es una variable donde guardas los resultados de axios
      arr: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
    }
  },
  methods: {
    updateTable(index) {

      // aquí se haría la llamada a axios
      // sería algo como axios.get('url').then(res => this.arr = res.data)
      this.arr.splice(index, 1)

    }
  }
}
</script>
```

## Con el paquete `laravel-vue-datatable`

En este caso tienes que hacer tus componentes hijo lo más genericos posibles, en el caso de `ButtonView`:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div class="row">
      <a v-bind:href="'/admin/users/'+data.id+'/edit'">
        <button :class="classes" title="Update">
          <span>
            <i class="fas fa-user-edit"></i>
          </span>
        </button>
      </a>
      <a href="#" @click="click(data)"> <!-- Usamos la función que pasamos -->
        <button :class="classes" title="Update">
          <span>
            <i class="fa fa-trash red"></i>
          </span>
        </button>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: {
    data: {},
    click: { // funcion que usaremos para pasar
      type: Function,
      default: () => {}
    },
    classes: {
      type: Object,
      default: () => ({
        'btn': true,
        'btn-primary': true,
        'btn-sm': true,
      }),
    },
  }
}
</script>
```

Mientras que en `AllUser` solo debes de especificar el `handler` dentro de `columns`:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <data-table
        :data="data"
        :columns="columns"
        @on-table-props-changed="cargar"
    ></data-table>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import ButtonView from "./ButtonView";

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      tableProps: {
        search: "",
        length: 10,
        column: "id",
        dir: "asc",
      },
      columns: [
        { label: "ID", name: "id", orderable: true },
        { label: "Name", name: "name", orderable: true },
        { label: "Email", name: "email", orderable: true },
        {
          label: 'Acciones',
          name: '', orderable: false,
          handler: this.deleteUserById, // declaramos que función tomar al hacer click al ButtonView
          component: ButtonView,
        },
      ],
    };
  },
  created() {
    this.cargar(this.url);
  },
  methods: {
    deleteUserById(data) { // esta es la función que tiene la lógica.

      // llamamos a axios para borrar el id
      alert('delete user' + data.id)

      // recargamos la tabla
      this.cargar()
    },

    cargar(url = this.url, options = this.tableProps) {
      console.log(url, options)

      // sustituimos esto por la llamada a axios 'get'
      setInterval(() => this.data = {
        data: [
          { id: 1, name: "bob", email: "foos@bar" },
          { id: 3, name: "alice", email: "foo@bar" },
        ],
      },10)

    },
  },
};
</script>
```

#### Puedes usar la siguiente [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/wispy-thunder-q8ff2?file=/src/AllUser.vue) (que soluciona el caso de `laravel-vue-datatable`) para guiarte mejor.

Comment: gracias por tu respuesta y tu tiempo. He aplicado lo que me has dicho, o eso creo ya que soy bastante novato con vue. pero no hace nada. Actualizo mi pregunta con el código actual de mis componentes allUser y buttonView

Comment: @scorpions78 y donde pusiste el emit y el recibir el evento en tu codigo? esta respuesta esta bien...

Comment: @gbianchi el emit lo he creado dentro del componente buttonView en .then en ese momento es cuando necesito que llame a recargar la tabla... No se si lo he hecho bien, lo dudo

Comment: Segui los pasos de esta respuesta. tu emit, tiene que ser en el momento que le decis al padre que ejecute una funcion... @scorpions78

Comment: @gbianchi gracias por tu respuesta... Estoy tratando de seguir al pie de la letra este ejemplo, aunque hay cosas que no se muy bien que hacen

Comment: @gbianchi y BrayanMartínezSantana tengo que decir, que estoy usando una librería para crear un datatable, no se si eso afecta a la lógica...

Comment: @BrayanMartínezSantana gracias por tu respuesta, pero sigue sin quedarme claro como actualizar mi tabla... lo siento

Comment: @scorpions78 tu codigo esta correcto ahora.. salvo que falta donde esta el boton en tu template, y que a tu boton (en el padre) le pongas que lea el evento @ delete

Comment: @gbianchi los botones estan en el componente buttonView ahí están mis dos botones que no son botones, son href a rutas de laravel. En el padre no se que poner

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/122463/discussion-between-gbianchi-and-scorpions78).

Comment: La respuesta ha sido actualizada, dime cualquier cosa

Comment: @BrayanMartínezSantana gracias por la ayuda, estoy viendo tu código en la demo y no borra la fila, pero voy a probar a implementar en mi código a ver

Comment: @BrayanMartínezSantana funciona de escandalo. gracias por todo

Answer (score 2):

Lo que según entiendo de tu pregunta, es que tratas de cambiar propiedades que recibe tu componente hijo desde un componente padre y, estos valores, recibirlos de nuevo en tu componente padre y que estos llamen a una función del mismo.

Suena confuso, pero creo que lo que necesitas son [eventos personalizados](https://es.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html). Te dejo un ejemplo:

```js
Vue.component('button-test', {
  props: ['item'],
  data() {
    return {
    }
  },
  methods: {
    change() {
      this.$emit("state", ! this.item)
    }
  },
  template: '<button @click="change">Cambiar State</button>'
})

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    state: false
  },
  methods: {
    show(value) {
      console.log(this.state + ' data por defecto') // antes del cambio
      
      this.state = value //cambiamos la data del padre con la información desde el hijo
      
      console.log(this.state + ' nuevo valor en el padre') //despues del cambio
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <button-test
    :item="state"
    @state="show"
  />
</div>
```

Te explico un poco: Recibo un props desde mi padre, con un status, este, al hacer click dentro de mi botón, llama a una función, emite un evento personalizado con un nuevo estado. En mi componente padre, lo recibo con su nombre, es decir `@state`, que ese fue el nombre de mi evento personalizado y le digo que va a ejecutar un función, en este caso, la función show que me muestra los valores por consola.

Espero te sirva de ayuda.

P.D: Te dejo [esta lectura](https://michaelnthiessen.com/pass-function-as-prop/) para que te des cuenta que incluso puedes pasar funciones como props y te dejo un ejemplo para que veas su funcionalidad:

```js
Vue.component('child', {
  props: ['data'],
  template: '<button @click="data">Ejecutar</button>'
});

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  methods: {
    parent() {
      console.log('Soy una función del padre llamada desde el hijo');
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <child
    :data="parent"
  />
</div>
```

Comment: gracias por tu respuesta y tu tiempo, pero no es lo que necesito a mi parecer. Necesito llamar a una función desde otro componente... Desde luego soy muy novato con vue y no entiendo muy bien todo

Comment: Es lo que necesitas, porque [si te fijas](https://michaelnthiessen.com/pass-function-as-prop/) incluso puedes mandar como props funciones o métodos, es decir, solo debes mandar tu método como un props y manejarlo en tu componente hijo y hacer el custom event de vuejs para devolverlo al padre.